# Pagination for blogger TOC

Tags: pagination, blogger, tableofcontents

How to make pagination below table on this page? My javascript code for pagination is working for few posts only.
http://pjoshi235.blogspot.in/p/blog.html

Comment: Please provide the code you have. That way other users can give you a proper answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

It's a static page. Maybe your template doesn't allow pagination to be showed in static page. Static page is the page that start with /p/. You should make an article in posts not pages.
Sorry for my bad english sir.